# Swift: UIImagePickerController will show UITabbar and it can't be dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am useing UIImagePickerController inside tabor. I have a detail where I have a disabled tabbar and a button. When I click the button UIImagePickerController will show.... when I dismiss the picker then UITabBar will show (I have tabbar.isHidden = true in viewDidLoad)...and I can't disable or hide it.... is that some kind of iOS bug?

Gif here....

[image]

Comment: It will not trigger viewwillappear